# Writing simple parser in Perl: having lexer output, where to go next?

Tags: perl, parsing, dsl

I'm trying to write a simple data manipulation language in Perl (read-only, it's meant to transform SQL-inspired queries into filters and properties to use with vSphere Perl API: http://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-60/topic/com.vmware.perlsdk.pg.doc/viperl_advancedtopics.5.1.html_)

I currently have something similar to lexer output if I understand it properly - a list of tokens like this (Data::Dumper prints array of hashes):

```
$VAR1 = {
      'word' => 'SHOW',
      'part' => 'verb',
      'position' => 0
    };
$VAR2 = {
      'part' => 'bareword',
      'word' => 'name,',
      'position' => 1
    };
$VAR3 = {
      'word' => 'cpu,',
      'part' => 'bareword',
      'position' => 2
    };
$VAR4 = {
      'word' => 'ram',
      'part' => 'bareword',
      'position' => 3
    };
```

Now what I'd like to do is to build a syntax tree. The documentation I've seen so far is mostly on using modules and generating grammars from BNF, but at the moment I can't wrap my head around it.

I'd like to tinker with relatively simple procedural code, probably recursive, to make some ugly implementation myself.

What I'm currently thinking about is building a string of `$token->{'part'}s` like this:

```
my $parts = 'verb bareword bareword ... terminator';
```

and then running a big and ugly regular expression against it, (ab)using Perl's capability to embed code into regular expressions: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html#A-bit-of-magic:-executing-Perl-code-in-a-regular-expression:

```
$parts =~ /
     ^verb(?{ do_something_smart })\s       # Statement always starts with a verb
     (bareword\s(?{ do_something_smart }))+ # Followed by one or more barewords
     | # Or
     # Other rules duct taped here
/x;
```

Whatever I've found so far requires solid knowledge of CS and/or linguistics, and I'm failing to even understand it.

What should I do about lexer output to start understanding and *tinker* with proper parsing? Something like 'build a set of temporary hashes representing smaller part of statement' or 'remove substrings until the string is empty and then validate what you get'.

I'm aware of the Dragon Book and SICP, but I'd like something lighter at this time.

Thanks!

Comment: I'll rephrase the question then.

Comment: Why don't you use an existing parser, like [Marpa::R2](http://p3rl.org/Marpa::R2) or [Parse::RecDescent](http://p3rl.org/Parse::RecDescent)?

Comment: @choroba, the documentation doesn't click. Don't know enough theory to make sense of it. Initially the question was on simple reading, but like that it would have been closed. I'd still like to go with writing the parser part on my own even if it's going to suck - it'd help me to understand how parsers work. If it was purely about getting things done I'd go with 'canned' requests and examples VMWare provides (it'm working on it too), but it seems to be simple and at the same time useful enough task to get me to learn something new.

Comment: Yeah, the docs on Parse::RecDescent are pretty intimidating, but the module itself is a really nice introduction to the topic, here's a more accessible tutorial: http://www.perl.com/pub/2001/06/13/recdecent.html . If you can get that working, you'll at least have a sense of what the whole process looks like.

Comment: [Parser::MGC](https://metacpan.org/pod/Parser::MGC) is the world's simplest recursive descent parser, done in a Perlish style without the code-generation complications of RecDescent. The [old 0.07 version](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/ARODLAND/TAP-Spec-Parser-0.07/lib/TAP/Spec/Parser.pm) of my TAP::Spec::Parser shows it in action in a way that might click. The only thing that's complicated about it is the hackery to deal with TAP's insistence on ignoring any line that can't be parsed.

Comment: @KevinG. thanks, it looks promising! I figure I could start with it and build up until it does what I need it to. A little bit sorry about not shuffling hashes around by hand but it seems to be just right balance of simple and complicated. Would make me think on better defining the language itself. Also, dates back to 2001, oh my.

Comment: Parser::MGC look like a great place to start

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in a couple of comments above, but here again as a real answer:

You might like [`Parser::MGC`](http://www.metacpan.org/pod/Parser::MGC). (Disclaimer: I'm the author of `Parser::MGC`)

Start by taking your existing (regexp?) definitions of various kinds of token, and turn them into "token_..." methods by using the `generic_token` method.

From here, you can start to build up methods to parse larger and larger structures of your grammar, by using the structure-building methods.

As for actually building an AST - it's possibly simplest to start with to simply emit `HASH` references with keys containing named parts of your structure. It's hard to tell a grammatical structure from your example given in the question, but you might for instance have a concept of a "command" that is a "verb" followed by some "nouns". You might parse that using:

```
sub parse_command
{
  my $self = shift;

  my $verb = $self->token_verb;

  my $nouns = $self->sequence_of( sub { $self->token_noun } );
      # $nouns here will be an ARRAYref

  return { type => "command", verb => $verb, nouns => $nouns };
}
```

It's usually around this point in writing a parser that I decide I want some actual typed objects instead of mere hash references. One easy way to do this is via another of my modules, [`Struct::Dumb`](http://www.metacpan.org/pod/Struct::Dumb):

```
use Struct::Dumb qw( -named_constructors );
struct Command => [qw( verb nouns )];

...
return Command( verb => $verb, nouns => $nouns );
```